# Como evito que la variable final sea 0?

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con la variable final, tengo un Set que le envió el ID que trae de la db y el Get que me retorna ese ID, asigne ese valor del ID a la variable final pero me retorna 0 el get de la variable final.
Como se debe asignar o usar esta variable para evitar valores null ??
Necesito usar el id ya que de este depende la carga de datos de un usuario que ingresa a un sistema.
Gracias

```
 public int getID() { // Este getter funciona bien si trae el ID

        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    //=====================================================
    // Le asigne valor de las dos maneras pero aun retorna 0 el getIDFINAL

    final int IDFINAL = getID();
    final int IDFINAL = ID;

    public int getIDFINAL() { // Este getter me retorna valor 0
        return IDFINAL;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta más simple en este caso tal vez sea que no quieres que esa variable sea `final`, porque ese modificador en tipos de datos primitivos te convierte tu variable en una constante.

Posibles alternativas basadas en mi explicación:

- Eliminar el modificador final `int idNoFinal;`, esto lo hará una variable común y corriente, se inicializará en cero si la declaraste a nivel de clase o en el valor por defecto para el tipo de dato que le asignes.
- Usar un Wrapper en vez de un primitivo con modificador final `final Integer IDFINAL`, tiene la aparente ventaja de permitirte trabajar con valores null, su valor por defecto es null, se le puede cambiar su valor ya corriendo y te asegura que cualquier clase que herede a la tuya no pueda cambiar la referencia de esa variable (ya sabes cosas de seguridad adicionales que proporciona final), y evita algunos problemas de hilos si corres tu clase de manera concurrente.
- Usar un Wrapper en vez de un primitivo, es practicamente lo mismo que la primera opción pero con la diferencia de que se inicializa en null que te va a ser algo impredecible el valor si usas tu clase con hilos y que es un poco más hackeable por alguien que quiera modificar tu clase mediante el agregar un hijo.
- Bloque estático, los bloques estáticos siempre se llaman en el momento indicado pero se consideran por lo general una mala práctica. Tiene la ventaja de que una vez que tu bloque estático se ejecuta si le puso el valor a una constante (osea un primitivo con el modificador final) el valor no se podrá cambiar posteriormente

  ```
  final int IDFINAL;
  static{ IDFINAL = (int)(1+Math.random()*5) }; // creo que lleva el ; no recuerdo bien :P
  ```

  - Finalmente una última opción que se me acaba de ocurrir es usar `AtomicInteger` no es lo más elegante pero está diseñado para ayudarte con problemas de concurrencia, es como un integer pero la obtención y establecimiento de valores se hace mediante métodos.

  Seguramente hay muchos métodos más, espero que con estos te puedas guiar.

Comment: Lo que necesito es que la variable a partir del momento que se asigne siempre esté hay su valor, lo necesito porque con ese valor que va ser el ID del usuario me va recargar información de la base de datos y ese id es el que necesito en varios formularios web que tengo dentro de un sistema. Entonces nose si a la variable final le estoy asignando bien su valor que sea = al getID pero aún así me sigue mostrando que la variable final es 0, en pocas palabras lo que deseo es una variable que me reciba el ID del usuario y siempre este ese valor hay ya que la llamaré desde varias clases

Comment: como te dije todas las formas te pueden ayudar, posiblemente la forma ne que lo piensas es la forma del bloque de inicialización estático. Saludos.

Comment: Lo que necesitas es guardar la clase yabsea en un bean de alcance de sesión @SessionScope o en en una variable de sesión. De esta forma siempre la tendrás con solo recuperarla de la sesion activa.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich eso haciendo la loca suposición de que tuviera un proyecto JavaEE o Java Spring verdad?

Comment: Supuse que tu proyecto es Java Web por tu comentario. Si es Web siempre tienes la opción de guardar variables de sesión.